# Lighttpd Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, lighttpd, pcre

I am trying to match any url that has /images/ , /styles/ , or /scripts/ in a lighttpd $HTTP["url"] statement. How could this be done? I am currently using "^/images/" , etc. and it's only working if that directory is in the beginning of the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/(images|styles|scripts)/
```

will match any string that has either `/images/`, `/styles/` or `/scripts/` in it.

Since you need to match the slash, use a different regex delimiter, e. g. `!`:

```
if ($subject =~ m!/(images|styles|scripts)/!) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"/images/|/styles/|/scripts/"